# Rails: Why does a migration require TWO steps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I generate a migration-file, for example `rails generate migration create_articles title description:text`, then I have to do an additional `rails db:migrate` afterward.

Theoretically it could all be done with one terminal-command as well: `Create table articles field:type ...`

**Why is the process of creating a database-table done in two steps?**

What's the benefit of the two-steps approach?

Comment: To have more control over the process. Imagine you misspelled or forgot a column then you can add it to your migration file before migrating.

Comment: @ErwinSchens Makes sense. Thanks. Grüsse aus dem Saarland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can edit the migration files before running a migration.
2. Every migration file has a timestamp. If you are working in a team and create a branch, your migrations are in your branch at first. If you deploy your branch your migration files will be deployed aswell. Because the migration files are independent from a database, you can track what happend to the tables and also update your local database to be up to date.